# How can I make a container with copy-on-write semantics? (Swift)

Tags: swift, optimization, struct, copy-on-write

I have a very large structure, which I want to ensure is not copied needlessly. How can I make a copy-on-write container for it?

Comment: What kind of large structure do you have?  I am asking because Swift already does (part of) the job for you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593992/when-does-the-copying-take-place-for-swift-value-types

Comment: @AntonBronnikov: I am aware of these optimizations. This question was meant to be an educational Q/A tutorial.

Comment: I understand.  That's why I ask about the kind of large structure this is intended for. The fact that such educational Q/A exists suggests that there is a need for it (e.g. what if not all use cases are covered by Swift compiler optimisations?).  It would only put things into a better picture if you could mention applicable use cases, as otherwise it would be a waste of effort to do/maintain something that Swift would do for you anyway and at no cost.

Comment: In Swift 4, use `isKnownUniquelyReferenced` instead of `isUniquelyReferenced`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A copy-on-write is usually a `struct` wrapper over some backing object.

```
public final class MutableHeapStore<T>: NonObjectiveCBase
{
    public typealias Storage = T

    public private(set) var storage: Storage

    public init(storage: Storage)
    {
        self.storage = storage
    }
}

public struct COW<T>
{
    public typealias Storage = MutableHeapStore<T>
    public typealias Value = T

    public var storage: Storage

    public init(storage: Storage)
    {
        self.storage = storage
    }

    public var value: Value
    {
        get
        {
            return storage.storage
        }

        set
        {
            if isUniquelyReferenced(&storage)
            {
                storage.storage = newValue
            }

            else
            {
                storage = Storage(storage: newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    public init(_ value: Value)
    {
        self.init(storage: Storage(storage: value))
    }
}

extension COW: CustomStringConvertible
{
    public var description: String
    {
        return String(value)
    }
}
```

The trick lies in asserting `isUniquelyReferenced` every time the boxed value is mutated. If the underlying storage object is singly referenced, nothing is to be done. However if another reference exists, one must create a new storage.

Is this code thread-safe? It is exactly as safe as any other value type, e.g. `Int` or `Bool`.

Comment: seem like the code in the `isUniquelyReferenced` never got chance be executed, I add a print statement inside, never got the output

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers aren't wrong, but there's a much simpler way.  The Swift team has [a list of performance tips](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst#advice-use-copy-on-write-semantics-for-large-values), and they say:

> The easiest way to implement copy-on-write is to compose existing copy-on-write data structures, such as Array.

It doesn't get much simpler than that!

Comment: Good advice, especially for beginners.

Comment: Not just for beginners -- that document specifically says "The intended audience of this document is compiler and standard library developers."

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit simpler example.

```
struct COWExample1<T> {
    private var box = Box<[T]>(value: [T]())
    var count: Int {
        return box.value.count
    }
    mutating func append(e: T) {
        ensureBoxUniqueRefed()
        box.value.append(e)
    }
    private mutating func ensureBoxUniqueRefed() {
        if isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC(&box) == false {
            box = box.duplicated()
        }
    }
}

private final class Box<T> {
    var value: T
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    func duplicated() -> Box<T> {
        return Box(value: value)
    }
}
```